# UI Button pressed distorts model

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I created a model programmatically and a UI Dialog that determines how the model should look. If I press the button in the UI to generate the model, the first time it will look exactly as expected but if I repeatedly press the button it will distort the model in a different way with every press. Is this a common problem for the UI button? If I call the function in my program to generate the model, there's no problem so I don't think its how I generate it. It's not the first time I've encountered this problem. The same thing has happened to me with a previous model. My UI is very simple and looks something like this.

```
try(destroyDialog ModelGenerator)catch()
rollout ModelGenerator "Model Generator" (
    group "Controls" (
        edittext myText "model options" 
    )
    button createModelButton "Generate Model"
    on createModelButton pressed do (
        delete objects
        generateModel (myText.text)
    )
)

CreateDialog ModelGenerator 300 300
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something wrong in the generateModel function, might be a scope issue with redefining globals (which would be why when running the whole thing it works) but that's really hard to say for sure when all I have is the function name.

Comment: Ok, I thought it was the button but this pointed me in the right direction and I fixed it. Thank you.